# Laravel octane not responding to request

Tags: laravel

Trying to run laravel octane. I do it as it is written in the documentation (I use a sail). A normal application without laravel works well, but after I set all the settings, rebuild the containers and run them, the application stops responding. All shops are empty. `sudo lsof -i -P command | grep LISTEN` gives output like this: [image]

What could be the problem and how to find it?